# How does one batch edit URL links in a Sharepoint LIst

Tags: c#, sharepoint

A site directory in my site collection on **serverA** has a list of all the sites in the site collection in a lists called Sites ( of course). Each listing has a URL field that will link you directly to the site in the list.

I backedup/restored this site collection from this server (**http://serverA**) to the production server (**http://serverProd**). The hyperlink addresses in the list were correctly updated. What was not updated was the "Display" property of these url links. So clicking on the link will take you to the right place on **serverProd** even though the display part of the field is still saying it will take you to **serverA**.

Is there a quick and simple way of batch updating these fields? At this point there are about 90 of them, so codeing against them is looking good. However, in the same amount of time I could (painfully) just do the editing through the SharePoint UI.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the "Edit in Datasheet" on your list. 
With about 90 you can easily do that manually. If thats to much work I would copy and paste from datasheet view into Excel and do some cleaver Excel functions to tidy it up. Then copy past back from Excel into the datasheet view.

Of course, starting off without server names in your description is best ;)